# Count the number of columns in R that have a non-zero value then return count in new column

Tags: r

I have an R table looking at meal sales data

The table showns the number of different types of meals sold e.g. fish, vegan etc.

I need to calculate an availability score for seafood, and have a new column containing this score for each day

e.g.
if there are zero-only values for a given row in the 'fish' 'fish.or.vegan' 'fish.or.veggie' 'just.mussels' or 'mussels.combined' columns, the new availability column shows the value 0
if there is just one non-zero value for a given row in the 'fish' 'fish.or.vegan' 'fish.or.veggie' 'just.mussels' or 'mussels.combined' columns, the new availability column shows the value 1
if there is just two non-zero values for a given row in the 'fish' 'fish.or.vegan' 'fish.or.veggie' 'just.mussels' or 'mussels.combined' columns, the new availability column shows the value 2
and so on

How can I add this simply?

The data is here:
`dput(head(mussel))`

```
structure(list(X = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L), Date = structure(c(18322, 18567, 18597, 18323, 18568, 18598), class = "Date"), Day = c("Tue", "Mon", "Wed", "Wed", "Tue", "Thu"), WeekofFullTerm = c(7L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 9L), MenuRotation = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Term = c("Spring", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Spring", "Autumn", "Autumn"), Period = c("Term", "Term", "Term", "Term", "Term", "Term"), Condition = c("Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Just Mussels", "Baseline", "Baseline"), Meal = c("Lunch", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Lunch"), MainMealsSold = c(151L, 152L, 182L, 156L, 171L, 117L), Fish = c(8L, 58L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 53L), Fish.or.Vegan = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fish.or.Veggie = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Just.Mussels = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L), Meat = c(10L, 9L, 91L, 82L, 28L, 10L), Meat.or.Vegan = c(0L, 43L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Meat.or.Veggie = c(52L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 71L, 0L), Mussels.Combined = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Unknown = c(39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Vegan = c(40L,  6L, 5L, 3L, 66L, 9L), Vegan.or.Veggie = c(0L, 0L, 69L, 37L, 0L, 42L), Veggie = c(2L, 36L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 3L), VegVeganPercent = c(27.8145695364238, 27.6315789473684, 45.6043956043956, 25.6410256410256, 39.1812865497076, 46.1538461538462),MeatPercent = c(6.62251655629139, 5.92105263157895, 50, 52.5641025641026, 16.374269005848, 8.54700854700855), FishPercent = c(5.29801324503311, 38.1578947368421, 4.3956043956044, 8.33333333333333, 2.92397660818713, 45.2991452991453), UnknownPercent = c(60.2649006622517, 28.2894736842105, 0, 0, 41.5204678362573, 0), MusselPercent = c(0, 0, 0, 13.4615384615385, 0, 0), MusselJustPercent = c(0, 0, 0, 12.8205128205128, 0, 0), MusselCombinedPercent = c(0, 0, 0, 0.641025641025641, 0, 0), SeafoodTotal = c(8L, 58L, 8L, 34L, 5L, 53L), NonSeafoodTotal = c(91L, 51L, 174L, 122L, 95L, 64L), SeafoodPercent = c(5.29801324503311, 38.1578947368421, 4.3956043956044, 21.7948717948718, 2.92397660818713, 45.2991452991453), NonSeafoodPercent = c(60.2649006622517, 33.5526315789474, 95.6043956043956, 78.2051282051282, 55.5555555555556, 54.7008547008547), MusselTotal = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 0L, 0L), NonMusselTotal = c(99L, 109L, 182L, 135L, 100L, 117L), VegVeganTotal = c(42L, 42L, 83L, 40L, 67L, 54L), NonVegVeganTotal = c(57L, 67L, 99L, 116L, 33L, 63L), MeatTotal = c(10L, 9L, 91L, 82L, 28L, 10L), NonMeatTotal = c(89L, 100L, 91L, 74L, 72L, 107L), FishTotal = c(8L, 58L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 53L), NonFishTotal = c(91L, 51L, 174L, 143L, 95L, 64L), Test100 = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, swiller! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Many apologies - I am new to this! I have now included the output of put(head(x)) directly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` to calculate the sum of non-zero values in selected columns for each row:

```
mussel$Score <- rowSums(mussel[, c("Fish", "Fish.or.Vegan", "Fish.or.Veggie", "Just.Mussels", "Mussels.Combined")] != 0)
```

This would give the result (showing selected columns and score):

```
mussel[,c("Fish", "Fish.or.Vegan", "Fish.or.Veggie", "Just.Mussels", "Mussels.Combined", "Score")]
```

**Output**

```
   Fish Fish.or.Vegan Fish.or.Veggie Just.Mussels Mussels.Combined Score
2     8             0              0            0                0     1
4    58             0              0            0                0     1
6     8             0              0            0                0     1
8    13             0              0           20                1     3
10    5             0              0            0                0     1
12   53             0              0            0                0     1
```